# Inverse `?` operator in Rust (aka return if Some/Ok)

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I am building a macro parser with [syn](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/) and need to check if a `ParseStream` is one of several [keywords](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/macro.custom_keyword.html). The code currently looks similar to this:

```rust
mod kw {
    syn::custom_keyword!(a);
    syn::custom_keyword!(b);
    syn::custom_keyword!(c);
}

enum MyKeywordEnum {
    A(kw::a),
    B(kw::b),
    C(kw::c),
}

impl syn::parse::Parse for MyKeywordEnum {
    fn parse(input: syn::parse::ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        Ok(if let Ok(ret) = input.parse::<kw::a>() {
            Self::A(ret)
        } else if let Ok(ret) = input.parse::<kw::b>() {
            Self::B(ret)
        } else if let Ok(ret) = input.parse::<kw::c>() {
            Self::C(ret)
        } else {
            abort!(input.span(), "Couldn't parse primitive type"); // Via #[proc_macro_error]
        })
    }
}
```

- Is there a built-in operator or macro to return immediately if an expression is `Option::Some` or `Result::Ok`?
- Is there a better way to organize these checks?
- Because `ParseStream::parse` statically compiles to the specific `impl Parse` type, I can't use `match`, right?

Comment: You can use [`lookahead1()`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/parse/struct.ParseBuffer.html#method.lookahead1).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good point, I ended up using a combination of this approach and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not. You could create a macro to do this, or you could use the `Result` combinator functions to make things a little prettier:

```rust
impl syn::parse::Parse for MyKeywordEnum {
    fn parse(input: syn::parse::ParseStream) -> syn::Result<Self> {
        input.parse::<kw::a>().map(Self::A)
            .or_else(|_| input.parse::<kw::b>().map(Self::B))
            .or_else(|_| input.parse::<kw::c>().map(Self::C))
            .or_else(|_| abort!(input.span(), "Couldn't parse primitive type"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best option for now